# How to run desktop application using SQL Server database on other computer without LAN or on different ip address like as web based

Tags: sql, windows, winforms, entity-framework, c#-4.0

i have a problem i'm new in window form application in C#. Currently finished 
a app that run on LAN means on the same network.
my Question is that i want to run the this application on different places 
means online this app using single sever .
please suggest me what i do for that 
Thanks to every one.

Comment: Open connection from your SQL Server to Internet, or to IP:s from where your application will work

Comment: Can you explain little bit more